# How to get duplicate rows but with different dates

Tags: php, mysql, join

My Table

```
| ID |   Date   | Next Date | 
| 1  |2014-12-23| 2014-12-25|
| 2  |2014-12-20| 2014-12-22|
| 3  |2014-12-19| 2014-12-21|
| 4  |2014-12-15| 2014-12-18|
```

How can I show duplicates when searching within date range in my search result query:

```
select * from my_table where date >= '2014-12-14' AND date <='2015-01-22' ORDER BY (date) ASC
```

My Results are:

```
1. ID: 4, Date: 2014-12-15, Next Date: 2014-12-18
2. ID: 3, Date: 2014-12-19, Next Date: 2014-12-21
3. ID: 2, Date: 2014-12-20, Next Date: 2014-12-22
4. ID: 1, Date: 2014-12-23, Next Date: 2014-12-25
```

What I want to do is show duplicates with date, next date and sorted by date, next date.

```
1. ID: 4, Date: *2014-12-15*
2. ID: 4, Next Date: *2014-12-18*
3. ID: 3, Date: *2014-12-19*
4. ID: 2, Date: *2014-12-20*
5. ID: 3, Next Date: *2014-12-21*
6. ID: 2, Next Date: *2014-12-22*
7. ID: 1, Date: *2014-12-23*
8. ID: 1, Next Date: *2014-12-25*
```

What would be a good solution for my situations?

Thanks

Comment: *"How to get duplicate rows but with different dates"* - Kind of an [**oxymoron**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymoron), wouldn't you say? *STOP, keep moving*.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do...

Comment: It appears based on your results you want to union my table with itself.... `Select mt1.*, 'Original' as src from my_table union ALL Select mt2.*, 'Duplicate' from My_table mt2`.

Comment: hmn. date >= '2014-12-14' AND date <='2015-01-22' would get all the rows that are duplicate or not duplicate, you're selecting a range that would show all the records for those dates, unless you issue group by or distinct

Comment: you have to specify a little more how your desired output has been put together, there is no logic between your database example and your result.

Comment: @RST, there is logic in his example. the entries with * around them are sorted

Comment: How would a union work with just one table? @xQbert

Comment: Based on your query, I don't understand why ID 1 is there ?

Comment: @edward did you try the above?  It simply queries the same table twice putting the exact same results into a set of data twice.  But I created a column called src to distinguish between the original and the duplicate.  I'm like others, I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but the union will result in the same result set you have listed.

Comment: @InnocentBystander that is not what his code looked like when he first posted it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
select "ID", "Order Date"
from
(
    (select "ID", "Date", "Next Date", "Date" as "Order Date" from Table1)
    union all
    (select "ID", "Date", "Next Date", "Next Date" as "Order Date" from Table1)
) as Table2
order by "Order Date"
```

NB: Change `Table1` to the actual name of your table.